Can we use structure ( "......," said someone of )?
Oh, This is my first question.
Can I grammatically use structure reported speech followed by "said someone of" according to using "say of" that can use instead of "about" in some contexts, such as

"I'm excited," said Donald, 65, president of the company, of a new project in his company.

Instead of "said someone about" such as

"I'm excited," said Donald, 81, president of the company, about a new project in his company.


Hello. Please read the Help section, top right, under the last icon. Your second sentence makes little sense in English. "said of x or said about x" but both are too far away in the way you wrote the sentences.

I would say that your sentences are not exactly 'wrong', but they are awkward.  There are too many words between said and of/about. A better word order would be "I'm excited", Donald... said of a new project".

If you say "I'm excited" you're not really talking about the project, you're talking about yourself. It's borderline in this case, but there are similar sentences which would be very odd.

@StuartF But it's normal to explain what you're excited about. If Donald had actually said "I'm excited about the new project" you could put that in the quotes, but in reported speach and paraphrasing it can go elsewhere.

Note that this is not reported speech, because the spoken words are quoted directly. If you want reported speech, try Donald, 65, president of the company, said that he was excited about the new project.

Neither.
"I'm excited" tells us something about the person who said it. It says nothing "of" or "about" the project.
I would say:

"I'm excited," said Donald, 65, president of the company, concerning a new project in his company.

What he said, he said about himself, but it was concerning the project. You could also say "regarding", "with regard to" or "in connection with" the project. It's a shame Donald couldn't have said "I'm excited about the project" then his quote would have spoken for itself.
